# How to get the extension of a file in an array using php

Tags: php

I have filenames stored in a database table along with other info. In a report I want the file extensions of the stored data. The database connection is made earlier in the code and not shown. Here's the code I use to retrieve the data:

```
 <php
    $query = $con->query('SELECT distinct(d.log_time), d.address, d.filename , i.country, i.area, i.city FROM download as d, lookup as i WHERE filename is not null and d.ref = i.id ORDER BY log_time, address, filename,country,area,city');


while ($row = $query->fetch()) 
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['log_time'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['address'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['filename'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['country'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['area'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['city'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

How do I get just the file extension for each filename?

Comment: You could use `explode()` on the file name.

Comment: Your title is misleading. There are many questions on SO related to getting file extensions.. Please search via Google

Comment: @Rotimi, I have searched and found nothing dealing with filenames within an array containing other data.

Comment: Use $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); See: https://thisinterestsme.com/php-get-file-extension/